# WordPress plugin loses $_POST variable on page refresh

Tags: php, html, wordpress, post

I'm writing a simple WordPress plugin for managing distributors in a database in the wp-admin area. The user needs to select State first and a listing will show of distributors in that category - and they'll be able to do CRUD.

The problem, the select action works, a postback is performed and I get to the query. The problem is when I do a 'refresh', the $_POST is not sent by the browser. I'm assuming this might be a WordPress thing, since this would typically work in normal situations. Any ideas?

Here is my example code:

```
function distributor_manager() {
    global $wpdb,$table_prefix;
    $disttable = $table_prefix.'tblDistributors';
    echo '<h1>Distributor Manager</h1>';
    echo '<form action="tools.php?page=distributor_manager" method="post" name="StateOption">';
    echo '<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle"><strong>Select State:</strong></td>
                <td>
                <select name="StateID" onchange="document.StateOption.submit();">
                <option value="0"> - SELECT STATE - </option>';
                $States = getStates();
                foreach ( $States as $abbreviation=>$fullname){
                    $display            = $fullname;
                    $xID                = $abbreviation;
                    if(isset($_POST['StateID']) && $_POST['StateID'] == $xID){
                        echo '<option value="'.$xID.'" selected="selected">'.$display.'</option>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<option value="'.$xID.'">'.$display.'</option>';
                    }
                }
                echo' </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>';
    echo '</form>';

    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
    if(isset($_POST['StateID']) && $_POST['StateID'] != '0' && !isset($_POST['form']) && !isset($_POST['formAction'])){
        if(!preg_match('/[A-Z]{2}/',$_REQUEST['StateID'])){
            echo 'ERROR';exit();
        }
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM ".$disttable."
                WHERE State = %s
                ORDER BY CompanyName";
        $distributors = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($sql, $_POST['StateID']) );
        echo '<div id="distributors">';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

I'm echo'ing $_REQUEST and $_POST. When I make the selection, these have values. If I refresh the browser, they come up empty until I make another selection from the drop down.

Comment: Unless you submit the form, the $_POST value doesn't get sent. If you refresh a form that's already been posted then it'll repost what it posted before assuming the code didn't redirect after the post.

Comment: Use ajax for performing `SELECT` or use SESSION's to store the posted values and use them later in your code.

Comment: a modern browser shows the warning about post-request reloading. Most likely your browser do not resend post data as a default behaviour.

Comment: Augwa... the browser is NOT reposting.. hence the problem.

Deadooshka - I am using a 'modern' browser. There is no warning about post-request reloading.. again, hence the problem.